# Energy and impurities balance for adsorption with a fixed bed (with description)?

Tags: concentration, energy, mixtures, kinetic-theory-of-gases, adsorption

Do you have any suggestion where to look for a source of information about energy and impurities (component) balance for adsorption of mixture CO2/H2O in fixed bed?

I have looked into many articles / some books (*Ruthven: Principles of Adsorption and Adsorption Processes* etc.) and most of them describe mass balance into a very details. I understood that, but these books do not contain information about how to express energy and impurities balance within the column.

Some articles focusing on adsorption modelling use energy, impurities, macro-micro pore balances etc. but their expression of these equation significantly differs (there are also difference in boundary and initial conditions). They also **do not explain expressions** used in the balances which I would very welcome while this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MaxW I am trying to find an analytical and numerical solution of column dispersive mass balance and energy balance. Similar equation can be found in many articles / books, but none of them shows how to solve these equation - integration by using give boundary / initial condition to express $\partial c \big/ \partial t$ and $\partial T \big/ \partial t$. From what I have found, it is probably necessary to rewrite the balances into dimensionless form (using characteristic numbers Re, Pe, Sh, ... and other dimensionless parameters), but I did not get any further, thanks.